# Log the URL of a page in which an iframe loads

Tags: iframe

I have a page which is going to be used on someone else's site in an iframe. I want to add a piece of code to the page that will load in the iframe that will get the URL of the page on which the iframe is loading, and store it either in a text file or a log file. Each time the iframe is loaded, I want it to get the URL for me, and store it in the file.

How can I do this?